# Tridion 2013SP1 HR1 Error - Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: 2013-sp1-hr1

I am upgrading a 2013 SP1 server to HR1.  When running the SDLTridion2013SP1HR1.exe file I get the below error message.  The system otherwise works fine and we have not had any db connectivity issues.  It hasn't had a hotfix or update in quite a while, so maybe the configuration changed since it was initially installed?  Which file does the .exe use to get the DB info?

We are using SQL Server aliases.  I assume this is the problem.  Any ideas on how to tell the CMS to use the alias?

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 3):

Running the .exe as an Admin user who installed Tridion (instead of an Admin user equivalent) solved the problem.  Also, we did not have any Publisher services running on the server, so we got an error "service __ failed to start. verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services".  Selecting ignore allowed us to finish the installer and then restart the server.